# Cannot await a .find method using mongodb c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am a novice so I apologize but I keep getting this CS1061 error when trying to await a .find() method. How do I await this find()?

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(mongoDBSettings.Value.ConnectionURI);
        IMongoDatabase database = client.GetDatabase(mongoDBSettings.Value.DatabaseName);
        _userCollection = database.GetCollection<User>(mongoDBSettings.Value.CollectionName);
        _partyCollection = database.GetCollection<Party>(mongoDBSettings.Value.CollectionName);
```

public async Task<IEnumerable> GetNearbyParties(string postalCode)
{

```
        var nearbyParties = await _partyCollection.Find(x => x.Address.postalCode == postalCode);

        return (IEnumerable<Party>)nearbyParties;

    }
```

MongoClient client = new MongoClient(mongoDBSettings.Value.ConnectionURI);
IMongoDatabase database = client.GetDatabase(mongoDBSettings.Value.DatabaseName);
_userCollection = database.GetCollection(mongoDBSettings.Value.CollectionName);
_partyCollection = database.GetCollection(mongoDBSettings.Value.CollectionName);

public async Task<IEnumerable> GetNearbyParties(string postalCode)
{

```
        var nearbyParties = await _partyCollection.Find(x => x.Address.postalCode == postalCode);

        return (IEnumerable<Party>)nearbyParties;

    }
```

I had it originally set up like this running synchronously:
public async Task<IEnumerable> GetNearbyParties(string postalCode)
{

```
        var nearbyParties = _partyCollection.Find(x => x.Address.postalCode == postalCode);

        return (IEnumerable<Party>)nearbyParties;

      
      



        //return results;
    }
```

But I understand that since it's an async method I should have an await when I try to search the database so that other things can run while that is fetched.

Comment: Is there a FindAsync method?

Comment: There are 2 find methods the synchronous `Find` that returns a cursor that can be used to iterate the results  and FindAsync  that returns and Task<cursor> that can be awaited  see https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.16/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_FindAsync__1.htm

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to call asynchronous API of Mongo not normal Find method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable> GetNearbyParties(string postalCode) {
    
            var nearbyParties = await _partyCollection.FindAsync(x => x.Address.postalCode == postalCode);
    
            return (IEnumerable<Party>)nearbyParties;
    
        }
```

Comment: it's not really true, Find also kind of supports awaiting, the only note that Find itself creates only `cursor` that doesn't call any actual command, you should call `await cursor.ToListAsync()` or similar logic

Comment: @dododo  maybe yes or maybe not but with the Find method directly you cannot use await and that is the real question or not ??? besides being a bad practice what you say. If there is a FindAsync method, the correct thing to do is to use that method.

Comment: the question what was done incorrectly with Find, it's incorrect to say: don't use Find and use something else.

Comment: not something else. FindAsync is the same thing that Find . But the correct way to work asynchronously is with FindAsync.

Comment: `Find` and `FindSync/FindAsync` are different methods that works in different ways